Excel Rank based on criteria
I am trying to rank the 'Max Reserve' based on 'Notification Month'. There are a number of  I have tried various methods I've found online and none seem to work as they should. I've added some example data in an image.

The second image is the ranking which I'd like the formula to do, based on the value and month:

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Dependent on what rank you want to give if 2 or more values are identical, this might be one of possible solutions:
=MAP(A2:A16,B2:B16,LAMBDA(a,b,MATCH(a,SORT(FILTER(A2:A16,MONTH(B2:B16)=MONTH(b)),,-1),0)))

Result:

